# Filter special characters except space in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have here a javascript code that filters special characters. But what I really want is to filter all special characters except space. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
function valid(f) {
    !(/^[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]/ig,''):null;
}
```

Comment: So what does PHP have to do with it? Have you tried, you know, adding a space character to the list of allowed characters in the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expression \s means space.
So please try this expression:

```
/[^\s]*/gi
```

this expression match all characters except " "

Comment: hi jason! i tried you code and it does filter all characters except "space". but what i want is for it to allow Alphanumeric characters AND "SPACE" to be inputted in a textbox.and filter other special characters. hope you can give me some more ideas.thanks!

Comment: Got it! Thank you guys for your help :) Thanks Jason Chelsea for the idea :) here's my code:

Comment: function valid(f) {
    !(/^\s[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9 ]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^\s;A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]/ig,''):null;
    }